# IBM HTTP Server is showing HTTP 1.1 500 status in logs

Tags: websphere-7

I am new to IBM HTTP Server and Websphere commerce. I am trying to access our application, but access.log file is showing `"HTTP 1.1 500"` status code. When I checked the `systemout.log` for `WAS Consol`e, It is showing below error:

```
webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Stores Request Servlet]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.commerce.seo.url.helpers.SEOURLMapperSource (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.init(RuntimeServletFilter.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:548)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:462)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:319)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:860)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:503)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:942)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
```

I checked for `SEOURLMappersource` class, and it is there in `SEO-BaseComponentLogic.jar`, which is already present in my `wc.ear` and other relevent classes to `SEO` are present in `SEO-BaseComponentLogic-FEP.jar.`

Please guide me for the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `(initialization failure)` means that a class failed initialization.  There should be a `Caused by` explaining that problem, but if there's not, search the logs for `SEOURLMapperSource.<clinit>` to find the underlying problem.  If that doesn't yield any results either, then wrap your `static{}` block in a `try{}catch{}` to print the real problem (and don't forget to move any `static ... = ...` initializations into the `static{}` block as well).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem described by this WC stack exception. I found out that on our system the owner/group for the related jar files was not set for the wc user but for the root user. Thus even though the class/jar present, it was not read due to permissions. This initialization exception went away after chown/chgrp and a restart.